# Makefile doesn't understand g++ but terminal does

Tags: c++, makefile, directory

[image]

Makefile

```
# Assignments
#########################################################
CC := g++
SRC := src
BUILD := build
INCLUDE := include
TARGET := bin/driver
LIB := lib
TESTS := tests

CFLAGS := -g -Wall -Wextra

PATH := -I $(INCLUDE)

#########################################################

driver: Logbook.o Entry.o main.o
    g++ Logbook.o Entry.o main.o -o driver

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp 

Logbook.o: 
    g++ -c $(PATH) $(LIB)/Logbook.cpp

Entry.o:
    g++ -c $(PATH) $(LIB)/Entry.cpp 

test:
    g++ -c $(PATH) $(LIB)/Logbook.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.exe driver
```

STDOUT

```
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $ ls
googletest  include  lib  main.cpp  Makefile  README.md  src
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $ make
g++ -c -I include lib/Logbook.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'Logbook.o' failed
make: *** [Logbook.o] Error 127
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $ ls
googletest  include  lib  main.cpp  Makefile  README.md  src
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $ g++ -c -I include lib/Logbook.cpp 
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $ ls
googletest  include  lib  Logbook.o  main.cpp  Makefile  README.md  src
mint@mint-VirtualBox ~/Desktop/Logbook $
```

The result expected is that g++ works while being called from inside the makefile but clearly doesn't

What exactly is going on here? there are tabs where there should be and running the compilation command while in the terminal works but the Makefile just doesn't want to agree that the g++ command exists.

Comment: Can you increase the size of your images, they are difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call the variable `PATH`, it overrides the default environment variable that tells the Makefile where to look for binaries. Just rename it to `CCFLAGS` or so.

```
CCFLAGS := -I $(INCLUDE)

Logbook.o: 
    g++ -c $(CCFLAGS) $(LIB)/Logbook.cpp
```

More details on PATH e.g. here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)